# Angular data bound to multiple bootstrap panels

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to extend this working example to include multiple panels that each show their own datasets.

I currently have two separate controllers and have bound each panel to each of the controllers, each containing their own individual datasets. However, the number of panels needs to be dynamic and built up based on the contents of a data feed.

Obviously, I don't really want to build a separate controller. It makes more sense to create a single data model and then bind the filtered result set to each of the panels e.g. flittered and bound based on the `panel_id:`

```
$scope.items = [
     {
       title: 'Header - 1',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 1',
       panel_id: '1'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 2',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 2',
       panel_id: '2'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 3',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 3',
       panel_id: '3'
     }
   ];
```

HTML Code:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
 <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- Panel 1 -->

 <div ng-controller="showhideCtrl_1">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">Panel 1 heading</div>
     <button class="btn btn-default " ng-show="hidevar" ng-click="hidevar=false">Back</button>
     <!-- List group -->
     <ul class="list-group" ng-hide="hidevar">
       <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showdes(item)"><a>{{item.title}}</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="panel-body" ng-show="hidevar">
       {{itemdesc.content}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Panel 2 -->

 <div ng-controller="showhideCtrl_2">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
     <div class="panel-heading">Panel 2 heading</div>
     <button class="btn btn-default " ng-show="hidevar" ng-click="hidevar=false">Back</button>
     <!-- List group -->
     <ul class="list-group" ng-hide="hidevar">
       <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showdes(item)"><a>{{item.title}}</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="panel-body" ng-show="hidevar">
       {{itemdesc.content}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here's the javascript code

```
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('showhideCtrl_1', function ($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
     {
       title: 'Header - 1',
       content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 1'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 2',
       content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 2'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 3',
       content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 3'
     }
   ];

   $scope.showdes = function(item){

     $scope.itemdesc=item;
     $scope.hidevar=true;
   }


 });

 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('showhideCtrl_2', function ($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
     {
       title: 'Header - 1',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 1'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 2',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 2'
     },
     {
       title: ' Header - 3',
       content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 3'
     }
   ];

   $scope.showdes = function(item){

     $scope.itemdesc=item;
     $scope.hidevar=true;
   }


});
```

Here's a working example of what I have so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/l65Q3MiofrNn5DyCgCfM?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a directive which will be a panel and pass that directive the items. Every HTML that belongs to the panel will go to its template:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('showHide', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items : '=',
      index: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="panel panel-default">\
         <!-- Default panel contents -->\
         <div class="panel-heading">Panel {{index}} heading</div><button class="btn btn-default " ng-show="hidevar" ng-click= "hidevar=false">Back</button>\
         <!-- List group -->\
         <ul class="list-group" ng-hide="hidevar" >\
           <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showdes(item)"><a>{{item.title}}</a> </li>\
         </ul>\
         <div class="panel-body" ng-show="hidevar">\
           {{itemdesc.content}}\
         </div>\
       </div>',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      scope.showdes = function(item){     
          scope.itemdesc=item;
          scope.hidevar=true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can make a controller which has the list of items list:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('main', function ($scope) {

 $scope.itemsList = [[
    {
      title: 'Header - 1',
      content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: ' Header - 2',
      content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    },
    {
      title: ' Header - 3',
      content: 'Panel 1-Dynamic Group Body - 3'
    }
  ],[
    {
      title: 'Header - 1',
      content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
    {
      title: ' Header - 2',
      content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    },
    {
      title: ' Header - 3',
      content: 'Panel 2-Dynamic Group Body - 3'
    }
  ]];


});
```

And in your HTML put ngRepeat to dynamically create a directive for every list available:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in itemsList">
   <show-hide items="list" index="$index + 1"></show-hide>
</div>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmSqAJ19xB6lnETJJWl7?p=preview).

Comment: Hi I needed to update my data model so that it contains the names of my panel headings since this data will be dynamically generated. I created a new Plunker here that shows that: http://plnkr.co/edit/XbX0hF8gFzolTdKF3qxp?p=preview. However, I can't quite work out how to bind that to my panels now.

Comment: you just need to change the ng repeat to list in itemsList.store. check this http://plnkr.co/edit/jPMzuEPe3rHHwJmowWZM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, however I think just overwrote your plunk update as I was probably editing it at the same time. So I just need the panel headings to reflect the categories and I think I'm there. :)

Comment: check the change to ng repeat http://plnkr.co/edit/x07zDwnCtvGjuRowk4sE?p=preview

Comment: One more (final) question. If I change my model to include a description for each of the panels, how can i bind that to the panel title so that it displays the description in the panel body when clicked. I also need the back button to redisplay the list. e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/kXGjEs46rN5eg6WyVWkS?p=preview –  user1513388 26 mins ago